# how to delete token django rest framework simple jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

Currently users are being issued a new token each time they login in, so there are several outstanding tokens linked to each user. This means the user cannot be deleted.

How can I delete tokens?

I'm looking for resources rather than help with coding please.

Update:
been researching my query today and I found flushexpiredtokens which I set up as a command and ran in the CLI and got rid of the expired tokens. However the current tokens are still preventing the user from being deleted as they are an outstanding token.

I'm very new to Django. I have some questions now:

1. do I need to set up a cron job?
2. can I someone make a function that when a user presses delte, it first expires all current tokens, then flushes the expired tokens and then deletes the user?
3. I ran the flushexpiredcommand I created in the CLI, should these commands be executed from the UI?

Comment: design the model to have a 1-1 relation  with the user and the token( I guess drf token has already it ..am not sure)

Comment: Please add your user and token models and how you are trying to delete users

Comment: @IainShelvington in models.py there is 
```from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin```
I can't see a users table in the db folder
Where would info about token models normally be kept?

Comment: @HarSin it depends on which package you are using to manage tokens and how it's configured, which package are you using? When you say `This means the user cannot be deleted` do you mean that a model/DB constraint is preventing you from doing so or something else?

Comment: @IainShelvington when Im on the Django admin page, I click on the user and click delete and the response is:
Cannot delete user
Deleting the user 'username123' would result in deleting related objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the following types of objects:

outstanding token

So I created the flushexpiredtokencommand which is a copy and paste of this on github (https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/token_blacklist/management/commands/flushexpiredtokens.py).part 1/2

Comment: @IainShelvington When I run that command the expired tokens are deleted but the current tokens remain and I continue to get the response above.
I keep seeing that we cant delete token if using JWT however the tech lead asked me to find a way around this as he saw an article sometime ago about it. Article was not provided part 2/2